# Getting Data from Java To JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, tags

It's been so long since I've worked this low in the stack that I can't remember how to get a value from Java to my JSP without Struts or Spring MVC or anything.

So if I have a String that I want to display in an arbitrary location in an HTML fragment, which could be anywhere, including in the middle of some JavaScript:

1. Where do I put the value so that it can be displayed? The response? The header? Somewhere else?
2. What's the tag + EL for grabbing it?

You would think you could get this info anywhere but a straight answer without teaching JSP from stem to stern has been very hard to come across. I even have pulled out my old "Head First JSP and Servlets" book but while it was good for learning the first time around, it apparently makes a terrible reference. Very hard to find specific items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using some Servlet like httpServlet. In that case add attribute to request and read its value on jsp with help of implicit varibles

in Servlet:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException, IOException 
{       
 request.setAttribute("name","XYZ");
}
```

in JSP:

```
<c:out value="${name}"/>
```

Comment: Hmmm... It goes in the request rather than the response? That might explain a thing or two. I'll give this a whirl tonight after work.